# Error while Using SVNKit in Linux

Tags: java, linux, svn, svnkit

I am using SVNKit... and its working fine in my Windows Local. But running it in Linux throws the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at svn_log.svnLog.Build(svnLog.java:156)
    at svn_log.svnLog$1.receive(svnLog.java:97)
    at svn_log.svnLog$1.receive(svnLog.java:68)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnReceivingOperation.receive(SvnReceivingOperation.java:78)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteLog.handleLogEntry(SvnRemoteLog.java:199)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository$1.handleLogEntry(DAVRepository.java:946)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.handlers.DAVLogHandler.endElement(DAVLogHandler.java:226)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.handlers.BasicDAVHandler.endElement(BasicDAVHandler.java:103)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseElement(NonValidatingParser.java:1358)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseRootElement(NonValidatingParser.java:375)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseDocument(NonValidatingParser.java:321)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:226)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readData(HTTPConnection.java:873)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readData(HTTPConnection.java:838)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.dispatch(HTTPRequest.java:218)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:447)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:365)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:353)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:708)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doReport(DAVConnection.java:335)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doReport(DAVConnection.java:325)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.logImpl(DAVRepository.java:991)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepository.log(SVNRepository.java:1035)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteLog.run(SvnRemoteLog.java:181)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteLog.run(SvnRemoteLog.java:35)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1235)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:291)
    at svn_log.svnLog.svnLogTest(svnLog.java:117)
    at bugdb.StartBuild.main(StartBuild.java:53)
```

the svn version in linux is 1.6.11 and svnkit used is 1.7.8

Comment: Do `java` versions vary between the 2 systems?

Comment: No... both are at 1.6.0_41